# Backbone keep url on refresh with f5

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Hello I am creating a backbone page and I use the controller to activate some view.

I have this controller:

```
 var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        "":"main",
        "your":"yourpost",
        "random" : "randompost",
        "featured" : "featuredpost",
        "sponsored" : "sponsoredpost",
        "post/:pos" : "post",
      },
      main : function () {
        console.log("MAIN_VIEW");
       main_view.render();
      },
      yourposts : function () {
        console.log("YOUR_VIEW");
        yourpost.refresh();
        yourpost.render();
      },
    ...
  // Instantiate the router
  var app_router = new AppRouter();
  // Start Backbone history a neccesary step for bookmarkable URL's
  Backbone.history.start();
```

When I have in the URL some like this:

> .../web/index.html#your

and I press F5 key, the Web browser write:

> .../web/index.html#

My question is, how I can keep the value of the url when I press f5?

Thanks!

Comment: Never had that problem.. What browser you use?

Comment: Backbone.history.start({pushState: true});

Comment: opengrid, your answer put in my browser : .../your, and this remove the /web/index.html and the page fail

Answer (score 0):

There was a fail in my code, I've done a session method that save the info in backbone var, and when I refresh if this hadn't the variables, this redirect to the main page. I have to modify the login method to can refresh the page without problems.

Sorry for all and thanks!!